# Saving parent_id relationship with ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Okay. I've had a real good look through SO and other sources returned by Google, but am yet to find an answer to my problem.

I have two models:

```
App.Kid = Ember.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr "string"
    parent: DS.belongsTo "App.Parent"

App.Parent = Ember.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr "string"
    kids: DS.hasMany "App.Kid"
```

Most questions on here discuss retrieving ember data relationships from sideloaded JSON data, which I'm capable of doing. What I need to know is how do I save the parent_id when creating a new kid?

At the moment I'm saving a new kid in the App.KidController like so:

```
App.ParentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    needs: [ "widgets" ]

App.KidCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    needs: [ "dashboard" ]

    saveChild: ->
        @content.get( "store" ).commit()
```

And when saving there is no parent_id to be seen, however I do get a new parent object (assigned to a parent key) with the id of 0.

Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update 1**

So using my actual situation I'll explain what I'm doing.

A user has several dashboards which have multiple widgets attached to it. My model structure looks like this:

```
App.Dashboard = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr "string"
    widgets: DS.hasMany "App.Widget"

App.Widget = DS.Model.extend
    title: DS.attr "string"
    type:  DS.attr "string"
    ...
    dashboard: DS.belongsTo "App.Dashboard"
```

Answer (score 1):

> One note at first, you have labelled your question with `ember-data` but your are defining you models using `Ember.Model.extend` which is used when using `ember-model` as your persistence library, therefore you should change it to `DS.Model.extend` or label your question differently, I'm assuming `ember-data` in my answer.

If your `App.Kid` model belongs to a `App.Parent` which has a `kids` array than your should use a `ParentController` to save the new Childs belonging to that parent this way you will have access to the parent `id` and it's `kids` array which you need to push the new Childs into.

### Example:

Given a simple template like this:

```
{{#each parent in model itemController="parent"}}
   <strong>(id: {{parent.id}}) {{parent.title}}</strong>
   <div class="well">
     <strong>Kids</strong>
     <ul>
     {{#each kid in parent.kids}}
       <li>(id: {{kid.id}}) {{kid.title}}</li>
     {{/each}}
     </ul>
     Kid name: {{input valueBinding="newKidName"}} <button class="btn btn-info" {{action saveChild newKidName}}>Add kid</button>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

You should then define a `ParentController` for each parent item and create there a `saveChild` function:

```
App.ParentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['dashboard'],
  saveChild: function(newKidName) {
   // get the dashboard id you want with
   // this.get('controllers.dashboard').get('id');
   // this assumes you have one dashboard?

   // create the new child
    var newKid = App.Kid.createRecord({title: newKidName});
    // push the newly created child into the parent's kids array
    this.get('content').get('kids').pushObject(newKid);
    // commit changes to the parent
    this.get('content').get('store').commit();
  }
});
```

See here for a simple demo of the example: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/115/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I'm definitely closer. However I still can't get the parent ID. If I do it as you demonstrated and add the ID under the parent key when creating a new record I get:

`Assertion failed: You can only add a record of App.Parent to this relationship`

Can you think of what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @Brayniverse, edited my answer, I added the `needs` so you will have access to your dashboard controller, I've also removed setting the parent explicitly, it should work without

Comment: Sorry I've gotten a bit confused by the switch from our original parent kid examples. Could you alter your use of dashboard to the original names?

Comment: I should not to avoid confusion. What I'm attempting to achieve is, a user has multiple dashboards and each dashboard has several widgets.

Comment: @Brayniverse, sorry I got you completely wrong then :( with just the `needs` in your question and no model definition I didn't get what you really wanted... if you could provide a bit more code of your setup I'll have another look

Comment: What would you like to know? I don't want to post all of my code as it's for somebody else and it would probably exceed the character limit on here.

Comment: @Brayniverse, how your models `Dashboard` and `Widget` look like for example

Comment: @Brayniverse, just to get it right this time, do you have `Parent` and `Kid` models as well? Or is it just for the explanation? And if you have them how do they relate to `Dashboard` and `Widget`?

Comment: lol I don't have parent and kid models they were merely for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out I was being a idiot. I'm using Laravel as my backend and when defining your models you need to define which attributes are fillable, however I forgot to add dashboard_id to the list. Everything works fine now.