# How to write Ember model for tree type json

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am very new to ember, can any one tell me how to write ember model for json show below. I searched lot but couldn't come up with any solution

```
 {id:1, name: "A", children: [
                    { id:1, name: "A1" },
                    { id:2, name: "A2" },
                    {
                       id:3, name: "A3", children: [
                               {
                                  id:1, name: "A31", children: [
                                          { id:1, name: "A311" },
                                          { id:2, name: "A312" },
                                   ]
                               },
                        ]
                    },
        ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I figure out the solution after a long time. I am answering this question because it may help others

here is the json data I have used

```
{"parent":[ 
       {"id":1, "name":"A", "children_ids":[1,2]}
],
  "children":[
         {"id":1, "name":"A1", "children_ids":[3,4]},
         {"id":2, "name":"A2", "children_ids":[5]},
         {"id":3, "name":"A11"},
         {"id":4, "name":"A12"},
         {"id":5, "name":"A21"}
  ]
}
```

Ember model

```
   App.Parent= DS.Model.extend({
         name: DS.attr('string'),
         children: DS.hasMany('App.Children')
     });

     App.Children = DS.Model.extend({
         name: DS.attr('string'),
         children: DS.hasMany('App.Children')
     });
```

Don't forget to make plural of children is children

```
      DS.RESTAdapter.configure(
         "plurals",{
           children:"children"
          }
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried something like the following? I have not worked with ember data yet, but i imagine it to work like this:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  id : DS.attr("number"),
  name : DS.attr("string"),
  children : DS.hasMany("App.Person"),
  parent : DS.belongsTo("App.Person")
});
```

Comment: thanks it works and no need to define id attribute in your answer... Can you give me any links to understand hasmany and belongs to relationships with json data example.. it would be great, I am really struggling understand them..

Comment: @AdarshUrs, I just answered a similar question couple of minutes ago, it includes a working demo, you could have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434901/saving-parent-id-relationship-with-ember-data/

Comment: @intuitivepixel thanks.. parent can hasmany kids and and kid belongsto a parent.. good example... What if a kid has some some other kids and those kids have some more and so on.. just like representing family tree.. see my question once.

Comment: and Can you tell me, is mavilein's answer correct method. what is the use parent property in it...